# Показывать по три элемента на странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Необходимо ограничить показ элементов на странице. Есть отзывы, необходимо показывать по три отзыва. Если их больше, то разделить по три отзыва на каждую страницу и добавить переключатель по ним.
Я то понимаю как в ручную засунуть в слайдер много элементов, но как автоматизировать это дело ? Чтоб на странице было не больше трех статей отзывов? Прикреплен код только мобильного маркапа.

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

```css
.feedback .items article {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.feedback .items article .text, .author, .date {
 color: #000000;

}

.feedback .items article .text {
 margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.feedback .items article .author {
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
.feedback .items article .date {
 margin: 0 0 40px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class ="feedback">
<div class ="items">

      <article>
       <p class = "text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
       <p class = "author">Мария</p>
       <p class = "date">01.01.2016</p>

      </article>

      <article>
       <p class = "text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
       <p class = "author">Валентина</p>
       <p class = "date">18.01.2016</p>
      </article>

      <article>
       <p class = "text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
       <p class = "author">Екатерина</p>
       <p class = "date">21.02.2016</p>
      </article>
   


     </div>
          </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я конечно могу ошибиться но это реализуется на php и довольно таки не сложно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте адаптивный слайдер, который будет менять количество слайдов в зависимости от ширины экрана/слайдера. Например, [Slick.js](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: я тоже к нему склоняюсь, но думал, что можно реализовать как-то без такого

Comment: @VladTeryoshin а для чего, собственно, изобретать велосипед?

Comment: я согласен с вами, сделал сликом.
я забыл, что там можно редактировать основные его функции.